# Ubuntu 16.04 apt upgrade leads to circular dependency

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade, dependencies

```
# apt upgrade
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-headers-generic : Depends: linux-headers-4.4.0-177-generic but it is not installed
 linux-image-4.4.0-177-generic : Depends: linux-modules-4.4.0-177-generic but it is not installed
```

Trying to install `linux-modules-4.4.0-177-generic`

```
# apt install linux-modules-4.4.0-177-generic
...
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-headers-generic : Depends: linux-headers-4.4.0-177-generic but it is not going to be installed
```

So, `headers-generic` requires **`headers-4.4.0-177-generic`** which requires `modules-4.4.0-177-generic` which require **`headers-4.4.0-177-generic`**

Question is how to resolve this circular dependency?

System always suggests to

> You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.

But I'm not sure if `-f` is best solution.

Comment: Try to remove both problematic packages and then install one (which will install the other).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_hell

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio Can you please add your solution as an answer? This is what works without `-f` (I have a little bit of an allergy for "forced" stuff... ideally nothing should be resolved in a forced manner). Command that finally worked was `apt install linux-headers-4.4.0-177 linux-headers-4.4.0-177-generic linux-modules-4.4.0-177-generic`. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Try,
`sudo apt install linux-headers-versionxx -f`
to install `linux-headers` dependency first.

If it is successfully installed then you want to try to install modules and other packages of it by using again`f` flag.

Comment: Hi, I appreciate your answer, although I'd prefer a solution without `-f`, so I gonna accept sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio's solution which seems to be THE way to go.

Comment: @Nemoden Hi! glad that it worked one way or another. Ultimately, what matters is not the answer that is given by users but if it resolved your problem or not. And by the way there is no need to have force phobia, ultimately sometimes there is no alternate but force your system to do what you want it to do.

Answer (score 1):

A usual solution in a case of circular dependency is installing all involved packages in a single `sudo apt-get install ...` command.

In your case, that would be

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-4.4.0-177 linux-headers-4.4.0-177-generic linux-modules-4.4.0-177-generic
```

or similar.

See also:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/584829/how-does-apt-handle-circular-dependencies

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/394670/what-to-do-with-a-circular-dependency-between-two-packages-in-fedora

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1910500

Answer (score 1):

Use `apt purge` to remove both packages of `linux-headers` and `linux-modules`.

Once they are both gone and cannot block the installation, install one of them,
which will also install the other.

You shouldn't have any circular dependency problem if both are not present.